# Python find the maximum total score from a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, iteration, dynamic-programming

I have a 6 * 14 matrix, each element of the matrix represents a score; my goal is to find the maximum total score as well as which element was picked from each row.

- Only 1 element can be selected for each row, and up to 1 element can be selected for each column.
- If the element of column 14 (last column) is selected, we will stop and add the score up to that element as total score.
- If the element of second column is selected, element of the next row can only be selected from the third column to the last column.
- We need to start from the first row, cannot skip it and go to the next row.

For example, if *x1,1* (element of first row and first column) is selected, then we go to the second row, and pick *x2,3* (can be picked from 2nd to the last column), then we go to the third row and pick *x3,6* (can be picked from 4th to the last column), then we go to the fourth row and pick *x4,9* and the fifth row to pick *x5,14*. We will pause here and not go to the last row since we have chosen a value from the last column. And the total score will be *x1,1* + *x2,3* + *x3,6* + *x4,9* + *x5,14* = 0.73 according to the matrix below.

`appr_0`:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.21 | 0.22 | 0.31 | 0.13 | 0.14 | 0.05 | 0.09 | 0.11 | 0.12 | 0.33 | 0.42 | 0.10 | 0.08 | 0.12 |
| 0.11 | 0.10 | 0.13 | 0.14 | 0.12 | 0.15 | 0.19 | 0.21 | 0.22 | 0.13 | 0.12 | 0.07 | 0.08 | 0.07 |
| 0.22 | 0.21 | 0.12 | 0.14 | 0.15 | 0.08 | 0.10 | 0.12 | 0.15 | 0.30 | 0.22 | 0.11 | 0.09 | 0.13 |
| 0.17 | 0.12 | 0.18 | 0.19 | 0.17 | 0.15 | 0.19 | 0.21 | 0.22 | 0.13 | 0.14 | 0.15 | 0.18 | 0.10 |
| 0.16 | 0.18 | 0.19 | 0.20 | 0.21 | 0.18 | 0.19 | 0.20 | 0.21 | 0.17 | 0.18 | 0.17 | 0.10 | 0.09 |
| 0.23 | 0.20 | 0.11 | 0.16 | 0.18 | 0.09 | 0.09 | 0.13 | 0.16 | 0.20 | 0.21 | 0.17 | 0.11 | 0.14 |

I have tried using iteration approach to find out the maximum score but it was very time consuming and the Python script wasn't able to run through it within a reasonable time. Just wondering if there is a way to write in another way and optimize it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['days_1', 'days_2', 'days_3', 'days_4', 'days_5', 'days_6', 'score'])

max_score = 0
curr_score = 0 
curr_max = 0

for j0 in range(14):
  curr_score = appr_0[0, j0]
  curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
  max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)
  
  for j1 in range(j0, 14):
    curr_score = appr_0[1, j1]
    curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
    max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)
    
    for j2 in range(j1, 14):
      curr_score = appr_0[2, j2]
      curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
      max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)  
  
      for j3 in range(j2, 14):
        curr_score = appr_0[3, j3]
        curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
        max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)
        
        for j4 in range(j3, 14):
          curr_score = appr_0[4, j4]
          curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
          max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)        
          
          for j5 in range(j4, 14):
            curr_score = appr_0[5, j5]
            curr_max = curr_max + curr_score
            max_score = max(curr_max, max_score)           

            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[j0, j1, j2, j3, j4, j5, max_score]], columns = df.columns)) 

df_max_record = df.loc[df['score'] == df['score'].max()]
```

Expected output `df_max_record` will look like (faked data):

| days_1 | days_2 | days_3 | days_4 | days_5 | days_6 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 13 | 0.95 |

Comment: It may be easier for us to understand what you need by adding an expected output table to your post.

Comment: Makes sense, just updated above.